# puppetlabs/apt and unattended-upgrades

Tags: security, puppet, apt

I want to have unattended-upgrades installed on my server and I want to edit the default config. I like to receive mail to confirm an upgrade, I know where to change it in config files.

[andschwa/unattended_upgrades](https://forge.puppet.com/andschwa/unattended_upgrades) doc clearly says that puppetlabs/apt can manage unattended upgrades but there is nothing said in the doc.

Can I have some help to configure unattended-upgrades with puppetlabs official apt module ?

I know that there is several modules to manage unattended-upgrades but I want to be sure that it is not possible with puppetlabs/apt before adding another module like [puppet/unattended_upgrades](https://forge.puppet.com/puppet/unattended_upgrades) as it is said that it is not available for debian 8.

Thanks

Comment: From andschwa/unattended_upgrades doc, [puppetlabs/apt](https://forge.puppet.com/puppetlabs/apt) should manage auto upgrades config. (I havn't enough reputation to put this third link in my question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> andschwa/unattended_upgrades doc clearly says that puppetlabs/apt can manage unattended upgrades but there is nothing said in the doc.

The functionality was removed from puppetlabs-apt in version 2.0.0 (now 4.0.0), and moved into puppet-unattended_upgrades (the Vox Pupuli module).

> I want to be sure that it is not possible with puppetlabs/apt before adding another module like puppet/unattended_upgrades as it is said that it is not available for debian 8.

This looks like a mistake in the metadata only that's been fixed in git since the latest release (2.2.0). The code to handle Debian 8 (Jessie) appears identical in the released version to git, so I'd say you can and should use this module to manage unattended-upgrades.